# XMPPFramework - Adding Contact to Openfire Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

How do I add a user to another user's contact in Openfire through XMPPFramework using Objective-C and how do I render it in an iPhone application?

Comment: after googling i come to know that there is a plugin is available called subscription. is anyone have idea on this..??

Answer (score 0):

Adding user to another user's roster.. by using modified user-service plugin did this magic..

Comment: hello mate have you succeeded in completing the app?

Comment: yes .. actually i have used user service plugin to add a user to another user's roster..

Comment: and do you think you can help me with this issue please? My brains are all over the place at this moment... I'm struggling to implement this for 3 weeks now...

Comment: @nik can you please help me connecting with openfire server with xmpp for yahoo gateway. i am not able to connect to it

Comment: @Ronak Yes whats ur problem on that ??

Comment: I am not able to connect to yahoo gateway no friend list is coming not even connect method called up

Comment: Not even connection method being called up

Comment: if you could come on private IM it will be more convenient